# Codeigniter sub-folder multiple controllers

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Here is my htaccess file and it works somewhat. Not matter what controller I specify it always goes to the home page

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my website URL

```
http://automationmetrics.local/automation/
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two rules get triggered on all the files, just like it says in the comment. So this one:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js)
```

seems redundant and removing it should solve the issue you're having.

Comment: This should probably be a comment rather than an answer, since it's a long shot - as numerous problems can occur and create the issue OP is having... but from what is given in the question, this could go as an answer.

Comment: Removing that line fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Some things I usually check when this happens to me:

- Have I enabled the mod_rewrite module in Apache?
- Have I set $config['index_page'] to blank?

If the above works, here's the one that I use, that's working on my end:

https://gist.github.com/petrepatrasc/6925413

If you're STILL out of luck, then try fiddling with the $config['uri_protocol'] parameter - I remember that I could only get it to work on Windows (with IIS at the time) using REQUEST_URI as a value. Might be related to that.